# Rewriter proxy URL with serve URL on webpack-dev-server

Tags: wordpress, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using "webpack": "^5.58.2" and "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1" on a WordPress theme development project. every thing is going good except one issue, I am using proxy to watch url (example.test) on server url (localhost:8080) here is my dev server config

```
 devServer: {
   devMiddleware: {
     writeToDisk: true,
   },
   historyApiFallback: true,
   open: true,
   compress: true,
   hot: true,
   port: 8080,
   watchFiles: ['../**/*.php'],
   proxy: {
     '/': {
       target: 'http://example.test',
       changeOrigin: true,
     },
   },
 },
```

I have some absolute link on site like http://example.test/sample-page, I want it like //localhost:8080/sample-page on serve/watch mode.
it works fine on "browser-sync-webpack-plugin" plugin.
Is it possible to achieve on webpack-dev-server? if possible how can I do that?